# Postfix/dovecot Relay access denied

Tags: centos, postfix-mta, dovecot

I've been trying to setup Postfix/dovecot.  I can connect through `telnet smtp` and send an email without any problems.

554 5.7.1 : Recipient address rejected: Access denied; from= to= proto=ESMTP helo=

**postconf -n**

```
   alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
debug_peer_list = 127.0.0.1
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
home_mailbox = Maildir/
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mail_owner = postfix
mailbox_transport = lmtp:unix:/var/lib/imap/socket/lmtp local_destination_recipient_limit = 300 local_destination_concurrency_limit = 5
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain, mail.$mydomain, www.$mydomain, ftp.$mydomain
mydomain = hungrypandasupplies.com
myhostname = mail.hungrypandasupplies.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
mynetworks_style = subnet
myorigin = $myhostname
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/README_FILES
recipient_delimiter = +
relay_domains = 
relayhost = mailout.serverpronto.com
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,             permit_mynetworks,                  reject_unauth_destination, permit
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = 
smtpd_sasl_path = inet:127.0.0.1:12345
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
soft_bounce = no
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

master.cf

```
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
```

I know it has something to do with Postfix and it's not recognizing my email address but I can't figure out how to fix it.

I have this in my /etc/postfix/virtual:

support@domain.com support

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to setup user for outgoing mail in your e-mail client program? This error appears when outgoing server needs to be authenticated.

Comment: Well now it's saying "Login to server mail.domain.com failed."  I enter in the password for the account and it doesn't accept it.

Answer (score 0):

The only Reason for `Relay Access Denied error` is invalid network configuration. To resolve this problem just edit `/etc/postfix/main.cf` 
And Change

```
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 your_network_ID/CIDR" (eg.192.168.0.0/24).
```